# VisualVM profile CPU but run() - Methods disturb

Tags: visualvm

i profile a big jboss server with a lot of classes in it. When i profile the CPU the result is always something like java.util.TimerThread.run() = 62% and java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() = 34,8%.
Under these two methods thousand other methods have 0%.
I think thats a bad bug, because most of these methods run in these Threads. But how can i see which one...
The ThreadDump - Function isnt usefull for this too.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know which part of the code is slow, it is better to start with CPU sampling. Once you know better (based on the sampling results) what is wrong, you can profile just part of your jboss server. See [Profiling With VisualVM, Part 1](https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/profiling_with_visualvm_part_1) and [Profiling With VisualVM, Part 2](https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/profiling_with_visualvm_part_2) to get more information about profiling and how to set profiling roots and instrumentation filter.